# pentaho report designer 5.0.1 parameter error

Tags: parameters, report, pentaho

I'm trying to search for a record in the database whith this code:

```
select att_value_1
FROM BUS_ENT_INSTANCE
where bus_ent_id = 1154 and att_value_1 = ${NumeroProcesso}
```

On the previous version, 3.9 , this piece of code used to work but in the new version, 5.0.1, it doesn't work.

It says "The parameters provided for this report are not valid."

When I substitute the "NumeroProcesso" by a process number directly instead of using a parameter it works, otherwise this is what happens.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you choose the option "Validate Values" when you've created your parameter? If yes, probably you aren't choosing a valid value.

I remember I had a problem with parameters too...and it was because the type of the parameter was incorrect. Make sure you selected the right "Value Type" for your parameter.

I hope it helps.

Regards,

Tatan.